# Circular import in FK default value when using custom model

Tags: django, foreign-keys, models

I'm trying to define in my app models.py a foreign key default value to a custom user model such as:

```
  owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=False, 
           default=get_user_model().objects.get()[0].pk)
```

The custom user model is also defined in the same models.py

However, I get the ugly circular import problem in another app models.py when they try to use `get_user_model()`:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to
model 'myapp.MyCustomUserModel' that has not been installed
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Try not not to call `get_user_model()` while setting `default` and check if this error persists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a method to get default owner instead of putting it as value.

```
owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=False, 
                          default=get_default_owner)

#this can be a global method and need not be in same model.
def get_default_owner():
    return get_user_model().objects.get()[0]
```

Comment: That worked. I previously was using this `default=get_default_owner()` and it didn't work